# Scroll bars not appearing in one of three scrollPanes

Tags: java, swing

I have a simple program that contains three scrollPanes. I have it set so that the scroll bars are always visible. For some reason, the scroll bars are only visible on two of the three panes even though the code for all three is the same. The only difference between them is that the third (pane with the problem) is in the south region of the border layout.

Code:

```
package SwingAssign2;

import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;

import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTextPane;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;

import javax.swing.JComboBox;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import javax.swing.SwingConstants;
import java.awt.GridLayout;

public class SwingAssign2 {

    private JFrame frame;
    private JTextField textField;

    /**
     * Launch the application.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    SwingAssign2 window = new SwingAssign2();
                    window.frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Create the application.
     */
    public SwingAssign2() {
        initialize();
    }

    /**
     * Initialize the contents of the frame.
     */
    private void initialize() {
        frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setSize(600, 500);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        JPanel panelTop = new JPanel();
        FlowLayout fl_panelTop = (FlowLayout) panelTop.getLayout();
        fl_panelTop.setAlignment(FlowLayout.LEFT);
        frame.getContentPane().add(panelTop, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        //panel.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEFT, 5, 5));

        JComboBox comboBox = new JComboBox();
        panelTop.add(comboBox);
        comboBox.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100, 20));

        textField = new JTextField();
        panelTop.add(textField);
        textField.setColumns(20);

        JPanel panelBottom = new JPanel();
        frame.getContentPane().add(panelBottom, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        panelBottom.setLayout(new BorderLayout(0, 0));

        JLabel status = new JLabel("Status");
        status.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
        panelBottom.add(status, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        status.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLoweredBevelBorder());

        JTextPane bText = new JTextPane();
        JScrollPane jScrollPane3 = new JScrollPane();
        jScrollPane3.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(
                JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
        jScrollPane3.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(
                JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
        panelBottom.add(bText, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        bText.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200, 200));
        //bText.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLoweredBevelBorder());

        JPanel panelCenter = new JPanel();
        frame.getContentPane().add(panelCenter, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        panelCenter.setLayout(new GridLayout(0, 2, 0, 0));

        JTextPane textPane_0 = new JTextPane();
        JScrollPane jScrollPane1 = new JScrollPane();
        jScrollPane1.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(
                JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
        jScrollPane1.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(
                JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
        panelCenter.add(jScrollPane1);

        JTextPane textPane_1 = new JTextPane();
        JScrollPane jScrollPane2 = new JScrollPane(textPane_1);
        jScrollPane2.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(
                JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
        jScrollPane2.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(
                JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
        panelCenter.add(jScrollPane2);

    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because of a silly mistake.

```
panelBottom.add(bText, BorderLayout.NORTH);
```

should be

```
panelBottom.add(jScrollPane3, BorderLayout.NORTH);
```

Comment: Thanks! Feel silly now.

Comment: @KevinSchultz BTW `JScrollPane jScrollPane3 = new JScrollPane();` should probably be `JScrollPane jScrollPane3 = new JScrollPane(bText);`